# Looping form based on select option value

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I have select option input. When I choose the number on it and than click the button, I want to display the forms. The number of form displayed based on the select option I choose. I don't know how to loop it in jquery and make the form display:none (before the button click the form is not visible). And is it posible to input more than one data in one table in the same time and how to do that? I've tried this
Thank You

```
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
   <label for="sel1">Jrekrut : </label>
   <select class="form-control" name="sel1" id="sel1" >
   <option selected>Pilih</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option> </select>
   </div>
   <form class="form-horizontal striped-rows b-form" id="form1">
     <div class="card-body">
     <div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
     <div class="b-label">
     <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label col-form-label">Full Name</label>
     </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Full Name Here">
       </div>
       </div>
</form>
     <script type="text/javascript">
var num;
$('#sel1').on('change', function(event) {
   alert("This is the value selected in solutions: " + $(this).val());
   num = $(this).val();
});

$("#btn").click(function(){

    //$("#form1").hide();
    $("#form1").toggle();
    console.log(num);

  });
```

Comment: Do you want to add the same field `num` number of times?

Comment: I want to display the same form based on the number I choose in select option

Comment: Same form or same input text field?

Comment: Upon click on button which form you need to show?

Comment: the same form, so the form get repeat

Comment: the form that has id="form1"

Comment: ahh. so suppose you choose three from the select box and it will create 3 three form with display:none by default and once you click on a button all three form will show?

Comment: yes. When I choose 3, than click button, it will show 3 same forms. the form is not visible at the beginning and will show the the button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey. So first you need to make a wrapper for all forms like '.form-container' and next you need to create html in javascript and push into it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sel1').on('change', function(event) {
           initForms($(this).val());
        });
        $('body').on('click', '.btn', function(){
            $('.form-horizontal').each(function(){
               $(this).show(); 
            });
        )};
    });
    function initForms(formCount){
        var finalHTML= "";
        for(i=0, i<formCount; i++){
            var tempHTML ='<form id="$formid$" class="form-horizontal striped-rows b-form" style="display:none;"><div class="card-body"><div class="form-group row"><div class="col-sm-3"><div class="b-label"><label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label col-form-label">Full Name</label></div></div><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Full Name Here"></div></div></div></form>';
            tempHTML = tempHTML.split("$formid$").join("form-" + i);
            finalHTML += tempHTML;
        }
        $('.form-container').empty().html(finalHTML);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question. I'm using your answer but that can't pass the value, when I var_dump($_POST) I get array(0) { }

Answer (score 0):

I have placed your `form` in a `div` with `id` equal to `form_container`, so that you can alter the number of forms in a cleaner way.

```
<div id="form_container">
    <form class="form-horizontal striped-rows b-form" id="form1">
        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

You can then use `append()` to add more some forms to your `div` in a `for` loop.

```
var num;
$('#sel1').on('change', function(event) {
    alert("This is the value selected in solutions: " + $(this).val());
    num = $(this).val();
    var formHTML = $("#form1").html(); // Get the HTML content of '#form1'
    $('#form_container').html(''); // Clear the contents of form_container
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        var id = i + 1;
        $('#form_container').append('<form class="form-horizontal striped-rows b-form" id="form'+id+'">'+formHTML+'</form>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

form display:none

```
<form class="form-horizontal striped-rows b-form" id="form1" style="display:none">
</form>
$('#sel1').click(function(){
    $("#form1").show();
});
```